# HTML variables inside a string

Tags: html

I'm trying to make a simple utility for my FAQ sections on a website. so far I have come up with a simple form that has 5 questions and 5 answers, and I am trying to grab the variables from each text box and insert them into the FAQ schema text, but I just can't figure it out.

This is what I have so far. I have tried using {} and @{} but it just displays them as text. I have written this already in PowerShell with winforms, but I find PowerShell much easier to use.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<head>  
<title>Output Tag</title> 
</head>  
<body>  
 <p>FAQ Schema Creator</p>
 <form onInput='faq.value="[sc_fs_multi_faq headline-1=\"h4\" question-1=\"q1.value\" answer-1=\"a1.value\" headline-2=\"h4\" question-2=\"a2.value\" answer-2=\"\" headline-3=\"h4\" question-3=\"\" answer-3=\"\" headline-4=\"h4\" question-4=\"\" answer-4=\"\" headline-5=\"h4\" question-5=\"\" answer-5=\"\" \"count=\"5\" html=\"true\" css_class=\"\"]"'>
      
  <label for="fname">Question 1:</label>
  <input type="text" id="q1" name="q1">
  <label for="lname">Answer 1:</label>
  <input type="text" id="a1" name="a1"><br>
<br>
  <label for="fname">Question 2:</label>
  <input type="text" id="q2" name="q2">
  <label for="lname">Answer 2:</label>
  <input type="text" id="a2" name="a2"><br>
<br>
<label for="fname">Question 3:</label>
  <input type="text" id="q3" name="q3"> 
  <label for="lname">Answer 3:</label> 
  <input type="text" id="a3" name="a3"><br>
  <br>
<label for="fname">Question 4:</label> 
  <input type="text" id="q4" name="q4"> 
  <label for="lname">Answer 4:</label> 
  <input type="text" id="a4" name="a4"><br>
  <br>
<label for="fname">Question 5:</label> 
  <input type="text" id="q5" name="q5">
  <label for="lname">Answer 5:</label> 
  <input type="text" id="a5" name="a5"><br><br>
 
Output is:<br><output name="faq"></output>
 
</form>
</body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try separating the string from the formvalues by replacing question-1="q1.value" with question-1=""+q1.value+"". Note the extra "+ and +". Like so:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<head>  
<title>Output Tag</title> 
</head>  
<body>  
 <p>FAQ Schema Creator</p>
 <form onInput='faq.value="[sc_fs_multi_faq headline-1=\"h4\" question-1=\""+q1.value+"\" answer-1=\""+a1.value+"\" headline-2=\"h4\" question-2=\""+a2.value+"\" answer-2=\"\" headline-3=\"h4\" question-3=\"\" answer-3=\"\" headline-4=\"h4\" question-4=\"\" answer-4=\"\" headline-5=\"h4\" question-5=\"\" answer-5=\"\" \"count=\"5\" html=\"true\" css_class=\"\"]"'>
      
  <label for="fname">Question 1:</label>
  <input type="text" id="q1" name="q1">
  <label for="lname">Answer 1:</label>
  <input type="text" id="a1" name="a1"><br>
<br>
  <label for="fname">Question 2:</label>
  <input type="text" id="q2" name="q2">
  <label for="lname">Answer 2:</label>
  <input type="text" id="a2" name="a2"><br>
<br>
<label for="fname">Question 3:</label>
  <input type="text" id="q3" name="q3"> 
  <label for="lname">Answer 3:</label> 
  <input type="text" id="a3" name="a3"><br>
  <br>
<label for="fname">Question 4:</label> 
  <input type="text" id="q4" name="q4"> 
  <label for="lname">Answer 4:</label> 
  <input type="text" id="a4" name="a4"><br>
  <br>
<label for="fname">Question 5:</label> 
  <input type="text" id="q5" name="q5">
  <label for="lname">Answer 5:</label> 
  <input type="text" id="a5" name="a5"><br><br>
 
Output is:<br><output name="faq"></output>
 
</form>
</body>  
</html>
```